# Parsing a UTF-8 XML file

Tags: python, xml, unicode, utf-8

I want to parse a file with minidom:

```
with codecs.open(fname, encoding="utf-8") as xml:
   dom = parse(xml)
```

Returns a UnicodeEncodeError. The XML file is in UTF-8 without BOM format and has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

in the first line.

If I first read the file, .encode("utf-8") it and pass it to parseString, it works. Is there a way to parse an UTF-8 XML file directly with minidom.parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the decoding to the XML parser; it'll detect what codec to use. Open the file *without* converting to unicode:

```
with open(fname) as xml:
    dom = parse(xml)
```

Note the use of the standard function `open()` instead of `codecs.open()`.

This applies to *any* XML parser; it is the job of the parser to determine from the XML prologue what codec to use for parsing the document. If no prologue is present then UTF-8 is the default.

Comment: To elaborate a bit in the answer, the OP problem is that `minidom.parse` expects a string of raw bytes and it will apply the declared encoding as needed, but they are are passing a string of chars... then it tries to decode the already-decoded chars and fails.